# PHP Composer - Unable to install composer on macOS Sierra

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer running the command provided on the getcomposer.org/download documentation site:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

But I get an error message saying:

```
Warning: copy(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in Command line code on line 1

Warning: copy(): Failed to enable crypto in Command line code on line 1

Warning: copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream: operation failed in Command line code on line 1
Yoshihiros-MacBook-Pro:~ yoshihiro$ php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"

Warning: hash_file(composer-setup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1
Installer corrupt
Warning: unlink(composer-setup.php): No such file or directory in Command line code on line 1

Yoshihiros-MacBook-Pro:~ yoshihiro$ php composer-setup.php
Could not open input file: composer-setup.php
```

I'm also trying to install it globally but I can't get out of this message. **Please help D:**

Answer (score 26):

I had same issues but this what I did:

- I copy paste this into the terminal `php -r "copy('http://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"` on the terminal which download the composer to the directory where you are currently In.

> (the problem was causing because of the `https protocol`)

- And then 
  `php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer` run this command, which installs the Composer to my bin folder so that i could run it globally.
- Then you have to unlink the composer `php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"`
- Finally check the see the Composer installed `composer -V`.

Good Luck !

Comment: great great great :D

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem-
here is the right way

1. clean dir > Terminal > mkdir composer
2. `cd composer`
3. `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
4. `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/`

   `vim ~/.bash_profile`
5. `alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"`

Comment: "sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ vim ~/.bash_profile" isn't work without using "mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target" or "mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source directory".

Answer (score 3):

I had same issues but this what I did:

- I ran `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` on my terminal which made composer to be installed on my PC.
- And then I moved Composer to my bin folder so that i could run it globally `mv Composer.phar usr/local/bin/composer`.

Comment: Great! I was able to download the "composer.phar" file but I'm not able to place it in the global directory so I can access the command on terminal. I've checked on finder and there's no "bin" directory on "/usr". I tried to create the route "bin/composer" and then place the file there but I'm still not able to execute the composer command on terminal.

Comment: @YoshihiroOrtiz, the /usr directory is hidden and can't bee seen through finder. go the the directory where you download the composer, then use this command to move $ sudo mv ./composer.phar /usr/local/bin/

Answer (score 3):

It works for me as follows:

I ran

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

on my terminal which made composer to be installed on my PC.
And then I moved Composer to my bin folder so that I could run it globally:

```
mv Composer.phar usr/local/bin/composer
```

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem and I try this step:

1. Open your terminal
2. Copy this code in your php folder, In My laptop, I have use lampp then I go to xampp folder.

`php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`

`php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`

3. So, if you have get this message below:

> All settings correct for using Composer
> Downloading...

> Composer (version 2.0.8) successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
> Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

4. You can copy this code:

   `php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"`
5. Untill here you have succesfully install composer
6. Check it with this code `composer`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The instructions in Composer [official page](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) is sometimes confusing

or not working on macOS Sierra.

But installation is still simple like before.Just simply run two lines of command on your Terminal.

1. curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
2. mv composer.phar usr/local/bin/composer

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same issues to install composer after a clean install of macOS Sierra. My solution to get it work:

1. Open your terminal
2. `sudo php -r "copy('http://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
3. `sudo php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"`
4. `sudo php composer-setup.php`
5. `sudo php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"`
6. `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

To verify if it's all installed properly type: `composer -V`

Answer (score 0):

Please don’t use any of it. I’m not saying its wrong.

Please follow the link [`https://getcomposer.org/download/`](https://getcomposer.org/download/) for installing latest version of composer.

The reason is because hen you download from `getcomposer.org` you are downloading latest file like `https://getcomposer.org/installer & composer-setup.php`.

And comparing with wrong SHA384 hash_file (like `e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae`), so it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just put `composer.phar` (which is what you end up with after you do the install) wherever you want and create a symlink in `/usr/local/bin/composer` to it using `ln -s`

Answer (score 0):

I use this method .and works fine for me on **ubuntu 17.10**

**1**-create file bash

***1-1*** Create a directory on the desktop.And then open the terminal

```
 sudo touch sh1.sh
 sudo 777 sh1.sh
```

**2**-edited file sh1.sh writing this statements

```
 #!/bin/sh

 EXPECTED_SIGNATURE="$(wget -q -O - https://composer.github.io/installer.sig)"
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
ACTUAL_SIGNATURE="$(php -r "echo hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php');")"

if [ "$EXPECTED_SIGNATURE" != "$ACTUAL_SIGNATURE" ]
then
    >&2 echo 'ERROR: Invalid installer signature'
    rm composer-setup.php
    exit 1
fi

php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RESULT=$?

exit $RESULT
```

**3**-on terminal run

```
./sh1.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Please just copy the link and paste it to your terminal:

> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

Now you can run composer without any error....

Answer (score 0):

You can easily download **PHP Composer** by following the official documentation, here's the [link](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

These are the steps.

1. `php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"`
2. `php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '906a84df04cea2aa72f40b5f787e49f22d4c2f19492ac310e8cba5b96ac8b64115ac402c8cd292b8a03482574915d1a8') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"`
3. `php composer-setup.php`
4. `php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"`
5. `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`

To verify if it's all installed properly type: `composer -V`

**This will work on both Linux and macOS.**